# How to fix tikz.sty problem

Tags: tikz-pgf, kile

I have installed ubuntu10.04 (32bit). My .tex editor is "kile2.1 beta 4".
Whenever I compile the following command with kile shows an error 'tikz.sty' not found.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)--(4,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I fix this problem in my system ubuntu10.04

Comment: Did you install `texlive 2009 distro` inside the 10.04 ubuntu repository using `sudo apt-get install texlive-full`  ?. if not, I recommend installing TeXLive 2013 vanilla using this  [How to install “vanilla” TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/15717). BTW 10.04 is a bit old, stick with latest LTS version of Ubuntu  LTS which is [12.04.3](http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/) now.

Comment: Test 1 to verify install: Does `kpsewhich tikz` at terminal return the path of tikz ? Test 2 to verify install: does `pdflatex sample2e` at terminal give a `sample2e.pdf`

Comment: I think you need to install `pgf` separately: `sudo apt-get install pgf` should get you PGF/TikZ.  Check for 10.04 (that's old) with `apt-cache search pgf`.

Comment: Soumitra, have you been able to resolve this?

Comment: jon is right. Had this error myself on another computer when I was too lazy to install from iso. The pgf package, as I keep forgetting and remembering every year, is independently installed from the pictures (which includes tikz but it's not loaded unless pgf is present) extras, the common, and the main tex on 'ix systems.

Comment: @jon Please make that an answer. That helped me.

Comment: @KaushalModi -- The question has been closed, so I don't think it is possible to provide an answer unless it is reopened somehow.